# Convert PWM to 3-level voltage

Tags: pwm, signal, wave, square

I want to convert a generated PWM by a microcontroller to a 3-level voltage.

[[image: this is the overall output]]

the maximum output voltage range is between -5 to 5 or -10 to 10 volts. Another point that may well be considered is that there is an optocoupler after the MCU. Also My micro is availabe to drive 6 PWM outputs.
I tried push/pull but I didnt get any right answer.

Comment: So what kind of "answer" did you get when you tried the push/pull?

Comment: with the push/pull I cant adjust the voltage level. in details, I want a RC filter to convert this pwm into square wave (voltage). but unfortunately due to high frequency (10khz) it was not something affordable! and also I cant adjust the voltage level due to the optocoupler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would still use the push-pull transistors. Either MOSFETs or BJTs.

The problem with push-pull is that you drive +VCC or -VCC. When both transistors are off the output is floating. Therefore you have to add either a weak pulldown (resistor) to ground or another transistor to provide bias (0V) when both push-pull transistors are off.
You'd need 2 I/O from a micro to control this 2 transistor + resistors setup or 3 I/Os for the 3 transistor circuit.

I hope this helps you a little. Good luck.